# Draw a PNG formated TPicture on a Canvas without using GDI+

Tags: delphi, png, gdi+, delphi-xe4

I need to draw a PNG (in a TPicture) on a canvas with the following requirements:

1. It needs to be very fast (due to target PC running a slow CPU).
2. It shouldn't require any additional libraries that will increase the size of the exe (due to target PC auto updating over a 2G mobile connection).

The code below does the job, but uses **GDI+** and:

1. Is much slower than drawing a simple non-transparent bitmap using `BitBlt`. On a fast processor the draw time increases from 1ms to 16ms. On a slow CPU it increases from 100ms to 900ms.
2. Increases the size of the exe by about 0.5MB.

Here's the GDI+ code. It is designed to fall back to a standard BitBlt if the :

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls,
  ComCtrls, ExtCtrls,

  GDIPObj, GDIPAPI;
...

procedure DrawPictureToBitmap(Bitmap: TBitmap; X, Y: Integer; Picture: TPicture);

  function PictureToGPBitmap(Picture: TPicture): TGPBitmap;
  var
    MemStream: TMemoryStream;
  begin
    MemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(MemStream);

      MemStream.Position := 0;

      Result := TGPBitmap.Create(TStreamAdapter.Create(MemStream));
    finally
      FreeAndNil(MemStream);
    end;
  end;

var
  GDICanvas: TGPGraphics;
  GPImage: TGPImage;
begin
  GDICanvas := TGPGraphics.Create(Bitmap.Canvas.Handle);
  try
    GPImage := PictureToGPBitmap(Picture);
    try
      GDICanvas.DrawImage(GPImage, X, Y);

      // Did the draw succeed?
      if GDICanvas.GetLastStatus <> Ok then
      begin
        // No, try a BitBlt!
        BitBlt(Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, X, Y, Bitmap.Height, Bitmap.Width, Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(GPImage);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(GDICanvas);
  end;
end;
```

**Update 1**

Using David's suggestion I managed to get rid of GDI+ using Delphi's built in PNG support.

```
procedure DrawPictureToBitmap(Bitmap: TBitmap; X, Y: Integer; Picture: TPicture);
var
  PNG: TPngImage;
  MemStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  PNG := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    MemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(MemStream);

      MemStream.Position := 0;

      PNG.LoadFromStream(MemStream);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(MemStream);
    end;

    PNG.Draw(Bitmap.Canvas, Rect(X, Y, X + Picture.Width, Y + Picture.Height));
  finally
    FreeAndNil(PNG);
  end;
end;
```

Unfortunately the draw time is exactly the same as the GDI+ method. Is there any way in which this can be optimised?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Good idea. This gets rid of the GDI+ dependency, but the draw time doesn't improve. See my update above.

Comment: Why not just DestinationCanvas.Draw(X,Y,Image1.Picture.Graphic);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you are needlessly taking an in-memory graphic, compressing to PNG, and then de-compressing. You can draw the graphic directly.

Simply call `Draw` on your bitmap canvas passing `Picture.Graphic`:

```
procedure DrawPictureToBitmap(Bitmap: TBitmap; X, Y: Integer; Picture: TPicture);
begin
  Bitmap.Canvas.Draw(X, Y, Picture.Graphic);
end;
```

At which point you'd probably decide that the `DrawPictureToBitmap` is pointless, remove it, and call `Bitmap.Canvas.Draw()` directly.

This will also have the happy benefit that your picture is not limited to containing a PNG image, as per the code in the question.

Comment: Great, that fixed both issues.